# CUPS (OpenSUSE) apply custom filter which is executed just before backend

Tags: cups

I've faced a task which contains several stages. One stage might be formulated as "catch every print job file before printing and save it in the specified place; print job file should contain information such as total pages for printing etc.".

As far as I understand, CUPS implements extensible pipeline which contains filter chain, backend and other parts.

During filter pipeline, generally PSTOPS or PDFTOPDF filters insert specific printjob information which i want to acquire.

I guess I have to implement custom filter which comes immediately after PSTOPS/PDFTOPDF and backups print job. In order to achieve it I am going to add

`application/vnd.cups-postscript application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 customFIlterName`
`application/vnd.cups-pdf application/vnd.cups-pdf 0 customFilterName`

to *mime.convs* (or *local.convs*).

Here come my questions:

1. Will my custom filters be called? (they have zero cost, but I am not sure CUPS will add this step to pipeline)
2. What should I do with queues which do not hit PSTOPS|PDFTOPDF filters?
3. Earlier or later, pipeline reaches backend part which communicates directly to printer. Should I try to make a backup at this stage instead of filtering stage? If so, how could it be implemented?

Thank you very much for response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to share what I've implemented in case it might be useful for someone else.

Device capabilities and some other information are included into related ppd files (etc/cups/ppd/DEVICE_NAME.ppd).

Ppd file contains string like "*cupsFilter: IN_MIME OUT_MIME FILTER_NAME".
This string indicates which filter should be called at last before backend.
String might be edited such as IN_MIME becomes CUSTOM_IN_MIME which should be declared into related cups mime description files. Then custom filter with, say, zero cost might be declared as IN_MIME CUSTOM_IN_MIME.

Then it's the only filter which understands CUSTOM_IN_MIME and thus must be called (actually, CUSTOM_IN_MIME is identical to IN_MIME and introduced only to force custom filter to be used).

In CUSTOM_FILTER we can implement whatever we want. That's the very powerful and generic approach to inject into CUPS.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Hi @metacube. I'm also working on quite similar tasks. In my task, I need to catch printer jobs, modify their content, and print an updated version. I would like to ask if you could provide some guidance.
How can I capture the printer job?
How do I create a custom filter?
How do I use a custom filter?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi @TrinhTran. I ended up with writing a cross platform solution which listens network and imitates a printing device according to IPP specification. In this case you just handle PrintJob requests according to your needs (I just save print job streams and send notifications to the other parts of my distributed system that later processes print jobs). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @metacube for quick response. I have been researching a lot but there isn't much information related to my task. AFAIK, that I need to create a custom filter and apply for printer. To be honest, your information is quite vague to me, could you provide more detail or any keywords, I will try to read it first?